# What's the purpose of the arg -XX:CompileCommandFile to cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.1

It seems to default to: -XX:CompileCommandFile=$CASSANDRA_CONF/hotspot_compiler a non-existing path in our DSC21 installation run by Oracle JRE 1.8 JVM. From Oracle JVM man page this option would be:

```
-XX:CompileCommandFile=filename
Sets the file from which JIT compiler commands are read. By default, the     
.hotspot_compiler file is used to store commands performed by the JIT compiler.

Each line in the command file represents a command, a class name, and a method name for which the command is used.
```

Question is would cassandra possible perform better if we used an Oracle JDK JVM w/a JIT vs JRE JVM?

Or has this HotSpot JVM got a JIT embedded within making it just as good as a JDK JVM?

```
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Either hints on which JVM is best to use and possible what should this option path contain, JIT commands and if possible which?